# Could someone explain to me "read var1 _ < <(ls -1l | wc -l); echo $var1"

Tags: linux, bash

```
read start _ < <(ls -1l | wc -l); echo $start
```

In particular:

- the underscore after read command
- the second minus (<)
- how does the "echo $var1" take the value of previous command

---

The original code:

```
read start _ < <(du -bcm kali-linux-2016.2-amd64.iso | tail -1); echo $start
```

I have just simplify the code because  **i'm interested in the syntax**

Comment: The `_` is just a regular variable name like `foo`, and is a common name when you don't care about it. As for how a value gets into `var1`, that's what `read` is for.

Comment: The command overall is a very brittle and cumbersome way to get the number of files in the current directory. [BashFAQ/004](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004) shows the robust best practice.

Comment: Please put the details in the question, not just the title.

Comment: `foo < <(bar)` is basically the same as `bar > tempfile; foo < tempfile`

Comment: Try this to understand `read name junk < <(echo fred 46)` then `echo $name`

Answer (score 1):

The following should help about the "_":
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280453/understand-the-meaning-of

This will about the "<<":
https://askubuntu.com/questions/678915/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash

please do more research before dumping it on SO to do your work.

and `echo` generally just repeats what it's told ('*echoes*' it). "`$`" is a signifier of variables in shell script, so $var1 is a variable named var1. In order to access any variable, you must prefix it with a '`$`'

Comment: i still don't understand the syntax code

Comment: What do you not understand? Please ask direct questions, and don't just proclaim that you do not understand. Before you ask SO, please ask those questions of google.